How to prevent password from being updated if empty in Rails Model and test it with RSpec?
I use Bcrypt gem for password encryption.
User model:
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true
  # ...
end

How to allow password to be blank when user is updated?:
expect(user.update(name: 'Joana', password: '')).to be(true)

But not update password?
expect { user.update(name: 'Joana', password: '') }
.not_to(change { user.reload.password_digest })

If you want to test it, mind to find user before updating it not to get false positives:
user = User.find(user.id)


If you don't want to update a value -- don't pass it to the update statement.

Did you consider a validation that ensures that a password is present?

Yes, I did, but it doesn't allow me to save other attributes in update statement when password is not present. @spickermann

Okay, I can sanitise it in the controller or front-end. Then should I add allow_nil: { on: :update }  to password validation?  @Stefan

If the user doesn't want to set a new password, the front-end should probably not send a blank value. In addition, calling params.compact_blank! in your controller would remove blank values.

it's purely a stylistic issue, but I would remove the password field, if blank, in a before_update callback in the model vs manipulating in the controller. It's the "Fat Model Skinny Controller" paradigm. In my opinion controllers get way too overloaded.

Yeh, I was thinking about that. However, I do not know how to do it. That's why I asked the question. @LesNightingill

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates(
    :password, 
    allow_nil: { on: :update }, # add this
    length: { minimum: 6 }
  )
  # ...
end

Thus these expectations pass:
user = User.find(user.id) # Refresh object as if you were in controller

expect(user.update(name: 'Joana')).to be(true)
expect(user.update(name: 'Joana', password: '')).to be(true)

expect { user.update(name: 'Joana', password: '') }
.not_to(change { user.reload.password_digest })

However, mind it would not update with actual nil password:
expect(user.update(name: 'Joana', password: nil)).to be(false)

So, it is counter-intuitive but it works.
Confirmation, and presence validations are not needed as they're provided by Rails.

You get the same result with or without allow_nil. Demonstration. And your question wasn't about nil, update your question please.

I think you got a false positive. If you actually find a user User.find(user.id), and then update it, it would fail. So it fails when you update it in the controller. True, my question wasn't about nil, and I don't want it to be about nil, I just mean that it is counter-intuitive that it doesn't work with nil. @Schwern

A better way of testing this would be to attempt to update the user and then use expect(user.authenicate(old_password)).to be_truthy instead. The password digest column is an internal impementation detail that your tests should not neccissarily be aware of.

The way I handle this in my app is as follows. This part of my code is a few years old, so there may be some improvements in more recent Rails versions, but it works just fine.
Of course, you are encrypting the password before saving in your database. Say the database field that stores the encrypted password is crypted_password.
Now in your User model you have:
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :password # this is the name of the parameter that comes in from the form on the front end

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def encrypt_password
    return if password.blank? # return early and don't assign any value to crypted_password, and it will not be changed
    self.salt = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--#{Time.now.to_s}--#{login}--") if salt.blank?
    self.crypted_password = encrypt(password) # encrypt, here, is a method provided by my included authentication module
  end

end


I use Bcrypt gem, so it would be quite different for me maybe.

UPDATE Now that we've seen the actual User model...
has_secure_password already works as you describe. It adds a bunch of its own validations, and it ignores an empty password.
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :password,
    presence: true,
    length: { minimum: 6 },
    confirmation: true
end

And some quick checks in Rails console.
3.2.2 :001 > user = User.create!(name: "Foo", password: "abc123")
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "password", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Foo"], ["password", "[FILTERED]"], ["password_digest", "[FILTERED]"], ["created_at", "2024-06-20 19:09:14.107560"], ["updated_at", "2024-06-20 19:09:14.107560"]]
  TRANSACTION (1.1ms)  commit transaction
 => 
#<User:0x00000001096d28d8
... 
3.2.2 :002 > user.update!(name: 'Joana', password: '')
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["name", "Joana"], ["updated_at", "2024-06-20 19:09:17.852613"], ["id", 6]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
3.2.2 :003 > user.update!(name: 'Joana', password: '')
 => true 
3.2.2 :004 > user.update!(name: 'Joana', password: nil)
(irb):4:in `<main>': Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters) (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

user.update!(name: 'Joana', password: '') only updates the name, not the password. This is a feature provided by has_secure_password.


You could add a `before_update` [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to your model to strip blanks.
class User
  before_update -> { self.restore_password! if self.password.blank? }

  ...
end

However, model callbacks can cause problems, especially when they're enforcing "business" rules which can change or not be universally applicable. And sometimes callbacks are skipped and they can complicate bulk database updates. This is the "fat model" problem.
Instead, do this as a model validation.
class User
  validates :password, presence: true

  ...
end

Normally you'd leave it at that and use the validation to inform the user of the problem.
If you want to update the other user attributes even if one of them is invalid, this is a questionable practice, you'd delete the blank password parameter in your controller. A better reason is if the user accidentally puts a space in the password field or something.
class UserController
  ...

  def update
    # or `params.compact_blank!` to do this for all parameters
    params.delete(:password) if params[:password].blank?
    ...
  end
end



But don't reinvent user accounts. Use devise. It's secure, well documented, and it works with many other gems.

Well, I am making an API with JSON Web Token. Devise works very well in a monolith. However, all the API solutions with devise I've seen so far are either unmaintained or seem to take as much work as not using devise at all.

On the other hand, if I remove the password from update statement user.update(name: 'Joana'), presence validation fails anyway. So I have to allow nil in the password validation on update as well, which seems counter-intuitive.

@ChiaraAni Did you try it? user.update!(password: nil) and user.update!(password: "") and user.update!(password: " ") will all fail the validation, but user.update(name: 'Joana') works fine because the password is not being updated. You do not need to allow nil. Maybe the misunderstanding here is that user.update(name: "Foo") and user.update(name: "Foo", password: nil) are different. There's a very important difference between passing in a key with a value of nil and not passing in a key at all.

@ChiaraAni I've updated my answer now that you've posted your User model. It already works as you described. Did you change your User model?

Mind to find user as if you were in the controller before updating it: User.find(user.id). Your approach is a false positive. It looks like it gets password from ruby memory so it doesn't fail as it should.

@ChiaraAni You're right! That is bizarre. There are internal differences between the objects, but that shouldn't matter for a validation. There's no "post create" or "post find" state. You might have found a bug. Another reason not to rely on this method and to instead sanitize your inputs.

@ChiaraAni I think this is a bug, or a misfeature, of has_secure_password. I asked a focused question about it.
